# Selected item from list getting highlighted

Tags: android, android-listview, highlighting

In following list, when I click any item which has width equal to 2 lines (*in below eg, **CNX SMALLCAP***), item gets highlighted appropriately.

Problem comes when I click any item which has width equal to 1 line (*in below eg, **ICICI BANK***), then along with the clicked item half of the above and below item is also getting highlighted.

Highlighting is always using width=2 lines.

What can be done to remove this?

I tried using `clearFocus()` and `clearAnimation()` inside `onListItemClick()` , but no luck.

**ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !!!**

[image: screen]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two lines, focusing both the lines when you have some content makes sense. Hence make the line which you are not using invisible or gone. You can also create separate custom adapter for your listview with single line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the selected color on the `ListView` not into the `ListView` item i.e. `TextView` which you have display as item. You can either set selected color on `TextView` or just set the `textview` background color as `#00000000`

```
<TextView android:background="#00000000" />
```

using this you define the transparency of the textview color with this